# Список стран и городов

Tags: веб-программирование

Где можно узнать список всех стран, список городов в каждой и часовой пояс в каждом городе для регистрации пользователей? 
Только список такой, чтобы можно было бы запустить какую-нибудь самописную утилиту, которая добавит их ВСЕХ сразу в базу, а не по одному и вручную :)

Comment: Могу выслать.. upd: [Список из более чем 300к городов мира](http://ifolder.ru/25015339) upd: [взято отсюда](http://www.world-gazetteer.com/wg.php?men=home&lng=en&des=wg&srt=npan&col=adhoq&msz=1500&geo=0)

Answer (score 3):

[MaxMind World Cities with Population](http://www.maxmind.com/app/worldcities):

> Включает в себя города, регионы, страны, широты и долготы.

Answer (score 1):

Список стран вам гугл подскажет, на той же википедии вроде есть... А вот список городов - сильно сомневаюсь, что найдёте! Сделайте город тестовым полем и всё. Да и часовой пояс дропдаун-меню - лучше всего :)

Comment: http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2 - вот что даёт википедия.
А как такое обработать?

Comment: Ну, так сделайте их список и напишите "самописную" утилиту :) Я фикстурами добавлял, но у меня проект был на джанго... Если у Вас тоже - могу поделиться файлом фикстур!

Comment: @_vb_ список городов с википедии можно обработать парсером.. (проходим по html и регулярными выражениями вытаскиваем нужную информацию)

Comment: можно, конечно, но задал вопрос, потому что может кто знает, где есть уже готовый список, ну или хотя бы всё на одной странице

Answer (score 1):

Я список городов, в одном из проектов брал из [яндекс погоды](http://pogoda.yandex.ru/orel/choose/), спарсить их оказалось не очень сложно - написал скрипт обхода и сохранения страниц + регулярка для выделения городов. Есть одно НО - если города в стране более или менее уникальные, то яндекс не предлагает выбрать область, т.е. если вам нужны будут области, то вам придется их брать их еще откуда-то.

В качесте указания часвого пояса лучше взять [UTC](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8F), для каждого пояса написать крупные города, люди дальше сами сориентируются по степени близости их к крупному городу.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.geonames.org/

Есть все необходимое API.
Еще есть вариант через google, но они сейчас шибко лимитят. Ну либо впиши им номер своей кредитки ;-)